# What is the proper way to encode SIMD types and functions that use them for the Objective-C Runtime?

Tags: rust, simd, metal, objective-c-runtime, metalkit

I'm developing an app in a language other than Objective-C and I came across [`newBoxWithDimensions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmesh/1562077-newboxwithdimensions?language=objc). It uses the `vector_float3` type which comes from the SIMD API.

I can not encode this function because of the `vector_float3` type.

I've found [Why can't gcc or clang properly @encode SIMD vector types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959915/why-cant-gcc-or-clang-properly-encode-simd-vector-types); the problem here is when `@encode` does not encode the SIMD types, then it can not create a proper form for those functions that use SIMD types and then the message sending verification fails. How can I bypass this encoding problem in message sending verification?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, so it's clear what you're having trouble with?

Comment: @E_net4 and Shepmaster my question is still correct, because the problem is still exist, and I only bypassing it. There must be some way to overcome this problem, I think other languages somehow are managing it. If I can make any time, I'm gonna take a look at them. And If I found my answer there, yes, certainly I'm gonna post my own answer below!

Comment: I know the question title is a little generic but it can be a good starting point for those who encounter the same problems and I think this is the first thing that comes in their head. 
And maybe the question body needs a little editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an experiment, I requested the method signature for `+newBoxWithDimensions:segments:geometryType:inwardNormals:allocator:`, using:

```
NSMethodSignature* sig = [MDLMesh methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(newBoxWithDimensions:segments:geometryType:inwardNormals:allocator:)];
```

I then enumerated its arguments and their type encodings.  It turns out that the signature just skips the two vector arguments. It shows a total of 5 arguments, which includes the implicit `self` and `_cmd` arguments, when there should be 7. The encodings are "@", ":", "q", "c", "@", the first two of which correspond to `self` and `_cmd` and the last three of which match the last three arguments of the method.

I think your safest approach is to write an Objective-C module that exports a function wrapping this method but where the vector components are passed separately (i.e. three `float` arguments for the dimensions and three `unsigned int` arguments for the segments). It would construct the vector arguments from those individual arguments and call through to the class method, returning its result.

Comment: `I think your safest approach ...` this is exactly what I don't like.

Comment: I only accept that because of that encoding suggestion, I thing this is correct, I'm gonna test it soon.

Comment: Um, that wasn't a suggestion. I think that the Objective-C runtime just can't cope with vector arguments and falls down (as you've found). I was intending to confirm that. I don't know Rust. Can it cope with an API that returns a function pointer with a given C signature? You could call `[MDLMesh methodForSelector:@selector(newBox...)]` and then treat the result as `MDLMesh *(*)(id, SEL, vector_float3, vector_uint3, MDLGeometryType, BOOL, id<MDLMeshBufferAllocator>)`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Work-around solution for Rust

For those who are using Rust and have the same problem, I found the work around for bypassing the errors, but keep in mind the problem still exists and my solution will make the developer blind in their debugging process.

- If you are using objc crate, try to remove the `verify_message` feature from your crate, else do not do message verifying.
- Use `simd` representation for your vector data and put your data in your message without any encoding.
- In this case you are insanely blind in your development, one way I can suggest is to take your debugging in to Xcode (this is not good too!).